# How would I get specific cookies?

Tags: cookies

i tried using browsercookie3 but it showed ALLL the cookies from my pc how do i just get my cookie called .ROBLOSECURITY?

i tried:

```
import browser_cookie3
cj = browser_cookie3.chrome()
print(cj.find(".ROBLOSECURITY"))
```

ive been trying and websurfing for like a hour lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each item until you find the cookie named `.ROBLOSECURITY`

```py
import browser_cookie3

def find_that_cookie(cookie_jar, name):
    for i in cookie_jar:
        if(i.name == name):
            return i.value

cj = browser_cookie3.chrome()
cookie = find_that_cookie(cj, '.ROBLOSECURITY')
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind adding an extra dependency, you can use `requests.cookies.dict_from_cookiejar`

```py
import browser_cookie3
from requests.utils import dict_from_cookiejar

cj = browser_cookie3.chrome()
cookie = dict_from_cookiejar(cj).get('.ROBLOSECURITY')
```